# Invokeresponse in botframework v4

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

How can I return an [InvokeResponse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.bot.builder.invokeresponse?view=botbuilder-dotnet-stable) in botframework v4 for C#? I need this to respond to compose extension activity messages. In the old framework this was done by returning in the response a `composeExtension` object from the controller.

How can this be done when implementing the `IBot` interface.

In the old framework there were MS Teams extensions, not available for the new framework version.

Comment: I you trying to send an invoke activity to the bot or to the user?

Comment: I was trying to respond to an invoke activity sent from the user (a compose extension) to my bot.

Comment: Are you using C# or NodeJS? On Ignite they announced that the .NET SDK will be released soon, NodeJS is still in the works. Until then you could write it yourself.

Comment: I'm using C# and .NET SDK was already released more than a week ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To respond to an invoke activity you have to set the "BotFrameworkAdapter.InvokeResponse" in `turnContext.TurnState` like in the below example

```
public async Task OnTurnAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
{
    if (turnContext.Activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Message)
    {
        // do stuff
    }
    if (turnContext.Activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Invoke)
    {
        // do stuff
        var invokeResponse = new InvokeResponse()
        {
            Body = response,
            Status = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK
        };
        var activity = new Activity();
        activity.Value = invokeResponse;
        // set the response
        turnCoontext.TurnState.Add<InvokeResponse>(InvokeReponseKey, activity);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Adrian Ber, I'm not able to completely understand your code. Please, could you be able to add some more comments explaining each of the steps. I'm stuck in the same issue as you were. For example, I suppose your ```response``` variable has been built using the proper JSON parameters, could you confirm?  Another thing is that I cannot find the proper method for sending the invoke response as you did, could you add some more detail in the call method (last line)?

Answer (score 0):

For what I **think** you are asking:
There is an example of handling an invoke response in [this sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/24.bot-authentication-msgraph).  In your [`OnTurnAsync`](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/42067607e6d4b520ba2bf35b11daef5a1a903450/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/24.bot-authentication-msgraph/GraphAuthenticationBot.cs#L70) you need to catch the [Invoke activity](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/42067607e6d4b520ba2bf35b11daef5a1a903450/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/24.bot-authentication-msgraph/GraphAuthenticationBot.cs#L80) and do whatever it is you need to do with the activity like in the sample.

I'm unsure which SDK you are using as you did not include it in your question but, a simple example in C# (Node would be similar) might look like this:

```
public async Task OnTurnAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
{
    if (turnContext.Activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Message)
    {
        //do stuff
    }
    if (turnContext.Activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Invoke)
    {
        //do stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: I said I was using v4. What you answered is how I handle an incoming activity. But for compose extension I need to return (not send) such a response.

Comment: This is how you would "respond to an invoke activity sent from the user".  I guess I'm totally unclear what you are asking please update your question and provide more detail. If your question is specific to MS Teams, please include the MS Teams tag.

Comment: I updated my question, but I also stated in the initial version that was about MS Teams.

Answer (score 0):

From the BF SDK v4 code here:
https://github.com/Microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/blob/4bb6b8d5faa4b252379ac331d6f5140ea27c177b/libraries/Microsoft.Bot.Builder/BotFrameworkAdapter.cs#L216
https://github.com/Microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/blob/4bb6b8d5faa4b252379ac331d6f5140ea27c177b/libraries/Microsoft.Bot.Builder/BotFrameworkAdapter.cs#L285

what you do is use `ITurnContext` to "reply" with a fake activity of type `ActivityTypesEx.InvokeResponse`, setting `Activity.Value` to an `InvokeResponse` object with your desired status code and payload.