# Which endpoint should be used for messaging extension responses?

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/messaging-extensions/what-are-messaging-extensions?tabs=dotnet) does not specify which endpoint to use when sending a response to an `invoke` (`composeExtension`) request from a Teams messaging extension. For example, [creating a conversation](https://DELETE%20/v3/conversations/%7BconversationId%7D/members/%7BmemberId%7D) uses `POST /v3/conversations`. Messaging extensions send requests to the same messaging endpoint for the bot, but nothing I've tried as a response has worked.

I've tried this:

```
POST https://smba.trafficmanager.net/amer/v3/conversations/a:12345ABCDE/activities

{
  "composeExtension":{
     "type":"result",
     "attachmentLayout":"list",
     "attachments":[
        {
           "contentType":"application/vnd.microsoft.card.hero",
           "content":{
              "title":"Test0 Title",
              "text":"Test0 text"
           }
        },
        {
           "contentType":"application/vnd.microsoft.card.hero",
           "content":{
              "title":"Test1 Title",
              "text":"Test1 text"
           }
        }
     ]
  }
}
```

The response was the following error:

```
{
   "data":{
      "error":{
         "code":"BadSyntax",
         "message":"Activity must include non empty 'text' field or at least 1 attachment"
      }
   },
   "code":400
}
```

I tried adding the response to an array as the value of the `attachments` key, but that didn't work either. The error indicated a malformed payload. At this point, I know a different endpoint must be required, but I can't figure out which one to use.

[Here](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/msteams-docs/issues/8373#issuecomment-1484177794) is a bug I filed against the documentation for more information, but I have not had luck with support via Github, which is why I am asking here.

Comment: Why would you be trying to invoke this endpoint directly?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Calling the APIs is a perfectly valid way to use the system. Not everyone wants the use the SDKs. They don't work in every environment and they're slow. The rest of the system has published APIs, but the messaging extensions were overlooked.

Comment: oh, I see now, this is to send the -reply-. I misread your question initially. Not sure why you're not using one of the SDKs, but perhaps you can use it temporary, and monitor what endpoint it calls?

Comment: @HiltonGiesenow There is no PHP SDK, which is the major limiting factor in my case. I also prefer to have more control over how the application works, but I digress. I am not sure how to use the SDKs for the other languages in a quick way. I could give it a shot, though, if Microsoft doesn't respond to my question on Github. Thanks for the thought.

Comment: At the end of the day, these SDKs are calling the underlying endpoints, so another option is just to go through the code for one or more of them, if you're at least able to read the code in another one of the languages? Start here: https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-sdk#quicklinks

Comment: In any case though, the endpoint I think will still be the same - looking at the original question again, I think the payload is the problem, not the endpoint.

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52598477/invokeresponse-in-botframework-v4